# Indexing Hierarchical Documents

Tags: c#, lucene.net, lucene.net.linq

I have a document structure like so:

```
public class DocumentA
{ 
  public String StringA{get;set;}

  public DocumentB DocumentB{get;set;}

}

public class DocumentB
{
  Public String IndexableContent{get;set;}

}
```

I want Users to be able to search for the reference of DocumentB but Lucene.NET Should return resultsets of DocumentA

I can't find any example on how to do this Using Lucene.Net.linq

Answer (score 0):

Lucene added index time join in version 3.4 but Lucene.Net currently is ported from Lucene version 3.0.

Since you can't do this in Lucene.Net, there's no way that Lucene.Net.Linq could support it.

Perhaps when a newer version of Lucene.Net is ported a feature like this could be added to Lucene.Net.Linq.

In the mean time you would have to store a unique ID for the child document as a field of the parent document. Then, when retrieving the parent document, you could retrieve the child document in a 2nd query by ID.